# Custom taxonomy returns 404 even with saving permalinks

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, 404-error

I'm trying to register a custom posttype and custom post type taxonomy. But when I create a term and click the button "view" to see the custom taxonomy page it returns a 404. I've tried resaving the permalinks a 1000 times, doesn't work.

```
function build_blog_post_type() {
        register_post_type (
            'blog',
            array (
                'labels'=> array (
                    'name'                      => 'Blog',
                    'singular_name'     => 'Blog bericht',
                    'add_new_item'      => 'Blog bericht toevoegen',
                    'add_new'                   => 'Blog bericht toevoegen',
                    'all_items'             => 'Alle blog berichten'
                ),
                'public'        => true,
                'menu_position' => 2,
                'menu_icon'   => 'dashicons-id-alt',
                'supports' => array('title'),
            )
        );

        register_taxonomy(
        'blog_taxonomy',
        'blog',
        array (
            'label'                 => 'Welke taxonomy',
                'name'                  => 'Welke taxonomy',
                'singular_name' => 'Welke taxonomy',
                'edit_item'     => 'Bewerk taxonomy',
                'add_new_item'  => 'Nieuwe taxonomy toevoegen',
                'menu_name'     => 'Welke taxonomy',
                'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
                'public'                => true,
        )
      );
    }
    add_action('init', 'build_blog_post_type');
```

URL I'm trying to acces: mydomain.test/blog_taxonomy/test-taxonomy

I have an 404.php with a specific main ID and a index.php with its own specific main ID, so I can easly see which is returned. There is no indication index.php is used

Comment: Could you post an example link you are using to access the taxonomy?

Comment: @WacławJacek I'm using the "view" button in admin, it gives me: https://mydomain.test/blog_taxonomy/test-taxonomy/

Comment: Are you sure it is a 404 error? Maybe the taxonomy link is working correctly and there just are no posts in that taxonomy?

Comment: @WacławJacek yes definitely. It even renders my custom 404 page.. :(

Comment: Do you have a custom 404.php template or is your index.php catching 404 errors? In the latter case, it is possible that if you do not have a taxonomy page template, WordPress is displaying the index.php file containing a "404 error" message instead.

Comment: @WacławJacek Yes, I do have an 404.php with a specific main ID and a index.php with its own specific main ID, so I can easly see which is returned. There is no indication index.php is used.

Comment: @Mooksz can you edit your question to include the information you posted in the comments? Soon it'll start hiding comments, and most people don't read them, so use the edit link to make sure your question is self contained and that users do not miss things

Comment: Also, do not use reserved keywords such as `blog` for post type and taxonomy names. For example on a multisite, sometimes the root site is given the `blog` prefix

Comment: I have tested the code you posted and it works fine. My only other suggestions as of now are to install the Query Monitor plugin and check what is listed as the environment (is this a taxonomy page? etc.) or this is a `.htaccess`/rewriting issue.

Comment: @TomJNowell will do thanks!

Comment: @WacławJacek hmm, weird. I will test more intensive tomorrow. Have to go now. Will update tomorrow. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @WacławJacek Query monitor returns: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS cs_posts.ID FROM cs_posts LEFT JOIN cs_term_relationships ON (cs_posts.ID = cs_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( cs_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (11) ) AND cs_posts.post_type = 'blog' AND (cs_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR cs_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR cs_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY cs_posts.ID ORDER BY cs_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10` en returns 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my solution.. In my functions.php I found the following functions which returns a 404 on several types:

```
  function remove_wp_archives(){
    //If we are on category or tag or date or author archive
    if( is_category() || is_tag() || is_date() || is_author() || is_tax() ) {
      global $wp_query;
      $wp_query->set_404(); //set to 404 not found page
      status_header(404);
      nocache_headers();
    }
  }
  add_action('template_redirect', 'remove_wp_archives');
```